# How to remove space between anchor text and border when padding is already zero'd?

Tags: css, text, border, html-lists, padding

I'm working on a navigation menu, and have created a  containing four anchor tags, as below:

```
 <nav>
<ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="active">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/portfolio/">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/" class="highlight">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

I've set a top border of 10px for each link, which I want to sit tight on top of the text. Despite setting padding to 0 in all the right places, I can't get rid of the padding. I've tried changing line height but this just moves the whole nav section up or down the screen, and doesn't affect the gap between the anchor text and the top border.

Here's the CSS (not including CSS resets etc, which I can post if needed, but these mostly came from HTML5BoilerPlate.

```
nav ul {
        padding-right: 24px;
        float: right;
    }

    nav li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: Oswald;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    nav a {
        color: #7a7a7a;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 16px;  
    }

    nav li a {
        border-top: 10px solid #7a7a7a; 
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: #555555
    }

    nav a.active {
        color: #555555;
    }

    nav a.highlight:hover { 
        color: #1f9c66;
    }

    a.highlight {
        color: #29cf86;
    }
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: One thought I had was that there might always be gaps above and below text to allow for special characters, so it would need a workaround?

Comment: Why do you have separate `nav a` and `nav li a` selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could translate the anchors a few pixels up via relative positioning:

```
li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 16px;  
    border-top: 10px solid #7a7a7a;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XQK9h/

Comment: Thanks, this moves the anchors up nicely but unfortunately also moves the border up. I don't want to separate the border into another html element as I want it to automatically set to the text width.

Comment: @jasonbradberry You could apply the border on the LI element and then ensure that it is not wider than the anchor...

Comment: Any idea how I might go about setting the LI border to automatically be the same width as the anchor?

Comment: @jasonbradberry Have you seen my demo? I set the border on the LI's and the border is not wider than the text...

Comment: Ah thanks, sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow and had missed the demo link. I've spotted my error, I'd left the margin left 16px under the anchor selector. Thanks for your help, this has worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

Set an anchor **float** which will remove the margin & padding in every web-browser.

```
#container li a {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you.

```
<style type="text/css">

nav ul {
    padding-right: 24px;
    float: right;
}

nav div {
    border-top: 10px solid green;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

nav a {
    color: #7a7a7a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #555555
}

nav a.active {
    color: #555555;
}

nav a.highlight:hover { 
    color: #1f9c66;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
a.highlight {
    color: #29cf86;
}

</style>

<nav>
<ul>
    <div><a href="/" class="active">BLOG</a></div>
    <div><a href="/about/">ABOUT ME</a></div>
    <div><a href="/portfodivo/">PORTFOLIO</a></div>
    <div><a href="/contact/" class="highdivght">CONTACT</a></div>
</ul>
</nav>
```